# Pandas fill column by count of other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Example df:

```
     company   vehicle registration
0   company1     truck       abc123
1   company1     truck      abcdefg
2   company1       car       234cse
3   company1  forklift          NaN
4   company1     truck        93ds2
5   company2       car      rentall
6   company2       car      rental2
7   company2     truck      rentals
8   company2     truck      rental*
9   company2       car      rental5
10  company3     truck       fdsa23
11  company3     truck        asdf4
12  company3     other       fdsag3
13  company3     other          NaN
14  company3     truck      gls319d
```

[image: sample_data]

My goal is to get counts by company and vehicle type (registration and vehicle columns will be dropped).

I've tried this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('path to csv', header=0)

df.loc[df.vehicle == 'truck', 'trucks'] = 1
df.loc[df.vehicle == 'car', 'cars'] = 1
df.loc[df.vehicle != 'truck', 'others'] = 1
df.loc[df.vehicle != 'cars', 'others'] = 1
```

from there I assume some sort of groupby and sum function would consolidate the rows and columns.

Unfortunately, this only fills in the vehicle columns with a "1" value rather than having the values in the respective columns.

My desired output is:

```py
company   trucks  cars  others
company1  3       1     1 
company2  2       3     0
company3  3       0     2
```

I'm sure this has probably been answered before, but my google-fu is weak this morning.

Cheers.

Comment: Some problem with solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by filtered categories in dictionary and replace all no matched values (NaNs) by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html).

Then pass to [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) and if order of output columns is important add [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df['new'] = df.vehicle.map({'truck':'trucks', 'car':'cars'}).fillna('other')
df = pd.crosstab(df['company'], df['new']).reindex(['cars','trucks','other'], axis=1)
print (df)
vehicle   cars  trucks  other
company                      
company1     1       3      1
company2     3       2      0
company3     0       3      2
```